# Fetch API not working on real device but working in emulator

Tags: android, api, android-emulator, react-native

I heve developed a website with an API (http://lkcfesnotification.000webhostapp.com/api/notifications)
. When I fetch and run in android emulator (Android Studio), all data got fetched image:(https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8lp3.jpg). But when I build an apk file and install it shows blank with loading circle (https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1vZn.jpg). Is this has something to do with the error what I got from my emulator screen(warning each child in a list should have unique 'key' prop) below are my code for my fetching the data screen

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Alert,
  FlatList,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TouchableHighlight,
  View,
  TextInput,
  ActivityIndicator,
} from 'react-native';
import { FloatingAction } from 'react-native-floating-action';


type Props = {};
export default class IndexScreen extends Component<Props> {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Announcements',
    headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#33FF99'
    },
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      data: [],
      isFetching: false,
     // value: ''
    };
    this._load = this._load.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this._load();
  }
  searchFilterFunction = text => {
    this.setState({
      value: text
    });

    const newData = this.state.data.filter(item => {
      console.log(item.type)
      const itemData = `${item.title.toUpperCase()} ${item.department.toUpperCase()}`;
      const textData = text.toUpperCase();
      return itemData.includes(textData);
    });

    this.setState({
      data: newData
    });
  };


  _load() {
    this.setState({isFetching: true});

    fetch("http://lkcfesnotification.000webhostapp.com/api/notifications")
    .then((response) => {
      if(!response.ok) {
        Alert.alert('Error', response.status.toString());
        throw Error('Error ' + response.status);
      }

      return response.json()
    })
.then(({ data }) => {
    this.setState({data});
    this.setState({isFetching: false});
})
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error)
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.textInputStyle}
          onChangeText={text => this.searchFilterFunction(text)}
          value={this.state.value}
          underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
          placeholder="Search Here"
        />
        <FlatList

          data={this.state.data}
          showsVerticalScrollIndicator={true}
          refreshing={this.state.isFetching}
          onRefresh={this._load}
          renderItem={({item}) =>
            <TouchableHighlight
              underlayColor={'#cccccc'}
              onPress={() => {
                this.props.navigation.navigate('Show', {
                  id: item.id,
                  headerTitle: item.title,
                  refresh: this._load,
                })
              }}
            >
              <View style={styles.item}>
                <Text style={styles.itemTitle}>{item.department}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.itemSubtitle}>{item.title}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.itemDate}>{item.updated_at}</Text>                
              </View>
            </TouchableHighlight>
          }
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => {item.title}}
          extraData={this.state} 
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

My expected output is that my real android device should show the same as my emulator.

Comment: I think fetch dont timeout and probably dont fail and waits for server to respond. Its possible that your device is not allowing your app to connect to the api endpoint

Comment: so how do i allow my device to connect to api endpoint

Comment: Does internet work on your device? Do you have app's internet usage policy in your android somewhere?

Comment: yes internet does work, not sure about the internet usage policy

Comment: Please show the log message of the response.

Comment: @Ruzanov log message on which the emulator or my real device